# Trigger is not working on jquery-steps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

plugin which I used is http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#advanced-form (you can look at clicking by code to see)

and I want to make custom button or trigger but my trigger function is not working on this plugin why that ?

my jquery codes

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#go-next').click(function(){
        $('a[href="#next"]').trigger('click');

      })

   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#go-next').click(function(){
            $('a[href="#next"]').trigger('click');

          });
          $('a[href="#next"]').click(function(){
              alert('d');
          });
       });

<body>
    <a id="go-next" href="#">gonext</a>
    <a id="next" href="#next">next</a>
</body>
```

Comment: you can accept this message in 8 minutes thank a lot it works as I expected :)

Comment: :-).. Please mark as answered. It will helpful for others and me :-)